# Update a JLabel from another thread without having to separate all my processes on threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I'm developing a big project on Java Swing. It has a database connection, external devices managing and sd-cards processing.

I currently have a lot of heavy processes that run on the EDT thread, and making separated threads for all of them is a long long task that I'm trying to escape... Besides, It would probably introduce a lot of concurrency problems that I am not willing to handle.

The thing is that I want to introduce a loading `JLabel` with a loading gif while the long busy tasks are being processed. It is also important to highlight that I want my whole swing interface to be blocked while the long tasks are being done, just like it happens now, EXCEPT for the loading label.

Is there a way to actualize that label from another thread?

Comment: _Is there a way to actualize that label from another thread?_ You can always implement your own EventQueue and decide to dispatch the events from another thread but I am pretty sure that you will run into severe concurrency issues. Blocking the UI is not difficult with a modal JDialog (which still allows painting to occur). Moving your long-running-task code to another Thread is not that complex but you will need to ensure that Swing updates are done on the EDT. There are no simple solutions to your problem. It will require some time and effort to set up, but this is the only "Good" solution

Comment: Thanks for answering. Well, what if I make another swing program that just displays the loading image and call it from my swing?? then the threading issue will be resolved by the OS, right?

Comment: @user2471107 Sure it will "work" but you won't have modality, if the user clicks on your original frame, your loading image will disappear. The user will be allowed to close your loading GIF, etc... And you will have to call that everywhere in your code. Again, this is spending almost as much effort as doing things right, to eventually have a poor result. Do things right: it will save you time and provide a nice result.

Comment: @user2471107 I don't understand your unwillingness to fix the real problem, while at the same time being ready to go to extremes working around it... It might take you a couple of days to properly fix, but it will be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about creating a good user experience, there really is no escaping using SwingWorker or similar, to offload work form the event dispatcher thread (EDT). If you need to *really* need to "block" the UI, you should use a JDialog with a progress bar or similar.

The short answer to your question is no. The Jlabel must be instantiated and added from the EDT.

However, you should be able to add the JLabel, you just have to make sure you do it **before** the long-running blocking tasks starts. Then remove it after it is done.

Anyway, this is a hack, and a lazy workaround for doing the right thing, and is not recommended. You might experience that you spend more time working around the issue and pulling your hair, than just do it properly with SwingWorkers.

Comment: *However, you should be able to add the JLabel, you just have to make sure you do it before the long-running blocking tasks starts* Incorrect. The `repaint` is scheduled and as long as that `repaint` did not take place, the `JLabel` is not visible. This is not so trivial to achieve

Comment: Thanks for answering. The thing is that even if I add it before the long running task, the animated gif is not displayed with its animation... just as an image... any ideas on how to get the animation displayed?

Comment: @Robin true. I'm not really recommending this approach.

Comment: @user2471107: You didn't mention animation in your question... I don't think it'll work with animation.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it clear that I wouldn't recommend doing it like this. :-)

Comment: @user2471107 you are trying to take a shortcut doing things the wrong way. This will get you only more issues to come and eventually it will take you longer to have something that only partially works, if it does not work at all. My best advice is to tell you to do things right and spend the extra effort doing it right.

Comment: Is there am easy way to make a whole netbeans subproject to run on a separeted thread?